# Unresolved references setting up Titan

Tags: java, gradle, titan

I want to setup Titan using Cassandra and Java.

I imported the libraries into my project using:

```
compile group: 'com.thinkaurelius.titan', name: 'titan-cassandra', version: '1.0.0'
```

and I copied the source example from:

https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/master/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/example/GraphOfTheGodsFactory.java

But the following things don't work:

```
import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanKey;
import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.attribute.Geoshape;
import static com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.INDEX_BACKEND_KEY;
import static com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.STORAGE_DIRECTORY_KEY;
```

don't exist

and the following throw errors because he can't resolve the references:

```
Configuration storage = config.subset(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.STORAGE_NAME_SPACE);
    storage.setProperty(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.STORAGE_BACKEND_KEY, "local");
    storage.setProperty(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.STORAGE_DIRECTORY_KEY, directory);

  Configuration index = storage.subset(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.INDEX_NAMESPACE).subset(INDEX_NAME);
    index.setProperty(INDEX_BACKEND_KEY, "elasticsearch");


  index.setProperty(STORAGE_DIRECTORY_KEY, directory + File.separator + "es");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mismatched version of `GraphOfTheGodsFactory.java`. You should refer to the tag `1.0.0` instead of `master`.

https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/1.0.0/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/example/GraphOfTheGodsFactory.java

Comment: Also `master` branch is woefully out of date. The default branch on GitHub is actually `titan10`, and the latest development is on `titan11` branch.

Comment: Which should be the version I should check out using gradle?
Is the titan10 stable already?

Comment: Your gradle import looks fine. `titan10` has some changes beyond `1.0.0`. I would suggest keeping with the `1.0.0` tag if you are using the `titan-1.0.0.zip` as that is the matching source code.